# How to force user to submit a class that inherits from a base class?

Tags: java

Suppose we have an abstract method that should return `Class`:

```
abstract class MainClass{
    abstract Class onCreateClass();
}
```

I have implemented the class like this:

```
class ChildClass extends MainClass{
    @Override
    Class onCreateClass() {
        return AnotherClass.class;
    }
}
class AnotherClass {

}
```

It works nice but now I want to declare some constraints on `AnotherClass`. For example I want to force the user of the `MainClass` to implement the `onCreateClass` such as it only returns classes that inherit from `BaseClass`:

```
abstract class MainClass{
    abstract Class<BaseClass> onCreateClass();
}
```

But it does not compile this:

```
class ChildClass extends MainClass{
    @Override
    Class onCreateClass() {
        return AnotherClass.class;
    }
}
class AnotherClass extends BaseClass {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use generic wildcards in `Class` declaration:

```
abstract class MainClass{
    abstract Class<? extends BaseClass> onCreateClass(); <-- all classes extends BaseClass
}

class ChildClass extends MainClass{
    @Override
    Class<AnotherClass> onCreateClass() { <-- compilation valid
        return AnotherClass.class;
    }
}


class AnotherClass extends BaseClass {

}

private class BaseClass {
}


class SecondChildClass extends MainClass{
    @Override
    Class<SecondAnotherClass> onCreateClass() { <-- compilation failed
        return SecondAnotherClass.class;
    }
}

private class SecondAnotherClass {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You go for:

```
abstract class MainClass <T extends BaseClass> {
  abstract Class<T> onCreateClass();
}
```

And now you could either go

```
class ChildClass extends MainClass<SomeSpecificClassExtendingBase> {
  class<SomeSpecificClassExtendingBase> onCreateClass() {
    return AnotherClass.class;
  }
```

or

```
class ChildClass<T extends BaseClass> extends MainClass<T> {
```

In other words: you can express certain *constraints* on generic types, and this is one of the easier examples on how to do that. Probably you want to do some further reading [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) or (hardcore) [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html).

Comment: is `class <T extends BaseClass>  MainClass` valid syntax for java?

Comment: @VladBochenin I didnt have my morning coffee yet. YOu are correct. Fixed! Thanks!

Comment: Nice to see even 27k+ Users can make mistakes ;P

Comment: @Fildor That is on purpose, so that the lower-reputation-ranking members of the community get their "i can make a significant contribution here" moments, too. ;-)

Comment: sorry, but this line `class ChildClass extends MainClass<T> {` also has error (Unknown class T). should be like `class ChildClass<T extends BaseClass> extends MainClass<T> {`

Comment: @VladBochenin Oh man, thanks again. Got your upvotes for that!